# if statement with xpath as expression

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to execute some code only if a given x Path exists, If it does not exist I need to look for another path and then execute some code.

I am trying to get to the same information but the structure that the information is in changes.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[contains(text(),'jakes')]/following-sibling::td/span/span"):
    extractBsr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[contains(text(),'jakes')]/following-sibling::td/span/span").text.split(' ')
    splitBr = extractBsr[0].split("#")
    splitBrComma = splitBsr[1].strip(',')
    br = int(splitBsrComma)
    if br < 3000:
        asin.append(x)
elif driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='jakesEL']"):
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='jakeEL']").text)
```

When I am on a page where the first xPath does not exists it is evaluating the xPath and throwing a error.

What is the proper way to structure this.

Comment: what is the error? it is probably throwing an error as it can not find neither the if xpath nor elif xpath.

Comment: when i am on the page where driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='jakesEL']"): exists it is saying driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[true(contains(text(),'jakes'))]/following-sibling::td/span/span"): does not exists

Comment: so it is doing what you have asked it to do. IF whatever THEN do it ... ELIF whatever THEN do it ... you are missing ELSE to cover the case if both cases IF & ELIF fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check existence of element without exception handling, try to use `find_elements...` instead of `find_element...`:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//th[contains(text(),'jakes'))]/following-sibling::td/span/span"):
    # In case of empty list you'll get False, otherwise True
elif driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@id='jakesEL']"):
    # The same here
```

You can also try to handle exception with `try`/`except NoSuchElementException` blocks